# remove white spaces from html text using jquery

Tags: jquery

English is not my native language So please No offence.
I want to get the text of the following `HTML` but I can see the white spaces.

I need it without extra white spaces.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
console.log($(".subTitle").text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
"<span class="subTitle"><span class="attributeTitleContainer"><strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Location</a></strong>: <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Chennai"</span>                <span class="titleSeparator"> => </span></span><span class="attributeTitleContainer"><strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Designation</a></strong>: <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Senior Graphic Artist"</span>                <span class="titleSeparator"> => </span></span><span>END</span>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove all the white-spaces. As you can see in the snippet, there are single spaces between them. I just want to remove other extra white-spaces.

Comment: Is having the script block source desirable? `console.log($(".subTitle").text().trim());` See my answer it's results is all the text except the code.

Comment: @zer00ne Again, formatting issues. I dont want to remove the existing whitespaces from the HTML but the extra white-spaces which I am getting from jQuery code. Your code does remove the white spaces but it removes the existing spaces too.

Comment: Define difference between white space, and existing spaces

Comment: there is a single space: 
<Location: "Chennai"> (actual html text)
after getting the trimmed text: 
<Location:"Chennai"> 
Hope, you can see the changes now. trimming will remove that single space too which I don't want.

Comment: I think I understand now, see updated answer.

Comment: @zer00ne Yes man. I got it. Thanks.. I am happy with all other answers but only thing missing was the extra space in reg exp.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace()` with this RegEx: `/\s/g`. Your OP code, (and apparently some other posts,) include the code within the `<script>` block with the exception of my answer. I believe this is undesirable. If so add the missing `</span>` end tag.

<del>console.log($(".subTitle").text().trim());</del>

## Demo

```js
var res = $('.subTitle')[0].textContent.replace(/(\s)+/g, ' ').trim();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
"<span class="subTitle">
  <span class="attributeTitleContainer">
    <strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Location</a></strong>: 
    <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Chennai"</span>
<span class="titleSeparator"> => </span>
</span>
<span class="attributeTitleContainer">
    <strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Designation</a></strong>:    <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Senior Graphic Artist"</span>
<span class="titleSeparator"> => </span>
</span>
<span>END</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `replace` of space at global scope like `replace(/\s+/g, '')` instead of `trim()`. `trim()` only trims the leading and trailing whitespaces.

```js
console.log($(".subTitle").text().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    "<span class="subTitle"><span class="attributeTitleContainer"><strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Location</a></strong>: <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Chennai"</span>                <span class="titleSeparator"> => </span></span><span class="attributeTitleContainer"><strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Designation</a></strong>: <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Senior Graphic Artist"</span>                <span class="titleSeparator"> => </span></span><span>END</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all whitespace characters use [String replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
console.log($(".subTitle").text().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
"<span class="subTitle"><span class="attributeTitleContainer"><strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Location</a></strong>: <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Chennai"</span>                <span class="titleSeparator"> => </span></span><span class="attributeTitleContainer"><strong><a class="Attribute" href="#">Designation</a></strong>: <span class="attributeTitleValue"> "Senior Graphic Artist"</span>                <span class="titleSeparator"> => </span></span><span>END</span>
```

Note that the character class `\s` matches all whitespace characters, specifically:

> Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form
>   feed, line feed and other Unicode spaces. Equivalent to [
>   \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff].